# Python session close after getting the results

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python code which uses session id and gets the output from an url.

I have to logout of the session once i get the results.Is there a way to close the session. I tried all the options such as

1. s = requests.session()
   s.config['keep_alive'] = False
2. r = requests.post(url=url, data=body, headers={'Connection':'close'})

When i tried to print the session id after the closing the connection it prints the same session id that is used to make the connection.

Comment: Does the backend API provide a logout endpoint? What happens if you specify a different/empty header?

Comment: For getting the session id i'm using credentials to login and get it.Yes it provides a logout endpoint.